# Minecraft Commands - Detecting an item on the ground with a custom tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect an item on the ground with a custom tag (e.g. `spark:1b`). I run this command:

```
/give @p blaze_rod{spark:1b} 1
```

Then I throw it on the ground and run this command:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={spark:1b}] run say hi
```

But nothing happens. How do I detect items (on the ground) with custom tags?

Comment: Does this work when you an existing NBT tag, like `CustomName`?  My guess would be no, since I don't think `item`s can `say` anything.  Also, are you sure the custom tag still exists on the item when you throw it?  Again, my guess would be that it doesn't.

Comment: The first one should work ("say" isn't something limited to certain entities), second one not. I'm pretty sure you can't just put anything into NBT.

Comment: @FabianRöling You can, those are called custom tags, and you can set either a numerical value (spark:3), or a bool value (spark:1b). Both are detectable using the nbt selector.

Comment: The `b` stands for byte, not bool, it stores 8 bits.  There are no actual boolean values stored in Minecraft NBT, although some values may have their range limited to be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

When an item is on the ground, it is an item entity. The data for this entity doesn't store specific information about the item itself, but rather has a tag for the item's data. The data for the item itself is stored under the tag 'Item:{}'.

As for your example, it would work, as the tag is stored on the item correctly. However, you forgot that, when testing for the item **entity** on the ground, the item **entity** has an 'Item' data tag that is used to store the data about the item itself. To test for this, you can simply modify the 'nbt={}' tag to account for this, so it would look like:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{tag:{spark:1b}}}] run say test
```

For the information on the item itself, it goes inside the 'Item' data tag. So, if you wanted to test for a specific item with a specific amount of that item, and with a specific NBT on that item, you could use:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:<itemName>",Count:<NumberOfItems>b,tag:{<NBT data of the item>}}}] run say test
```

*Be sure to include the 'b' after the count for the number of items*

If you don't want to check for a specific one of these, just leave them out of the 'Item' tag, like I have done with the first command.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't consider that entities might have a separate data tag for item data.